# How to append <option> tags to a <select> statement in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I am trying to dynamically populate `<option>` tags within a `<select>` menu, however I am having trouble doing so. The way I want to do this is in a for loop, where JS cycles through however many options there are, and appends the options to the select tag.

The bit of code that doesn't work (I reckon) is this bit: (all relevant code is below)

```
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //how can I do this part?
            item.appendChild((option + i + 1));
        }
```

I want it to cycle through and, if `count = 2` for example, append the options.

So when `i = 0` it will do: `item.appendChild((option1));` and when `i = 1` it will do `item.appendChild(option2);` to my `<select id='_second'>` menu

Im not sure what's going on, if someone could give me a sense of direction, that'd be much appreciated.

```
//Javascript
    myFunction = () => {
        //get value of selected <option> in a separate <select> drop down
        var type = document.getElementById('_first').value;
        //get the second <select>
        var item = document.getElementById('_second');
        //set count variable to know how many <options> there should be in second <select> drop down
        var count;
        //assess value
        switch (type) {
            case '1': //First case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText1';
                count = 1;
                break;
            case '2': //Second case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText2';
                var option2 = document.createElement('option');
                    option2.text = 'SomeText3';
                count = 2;
                break;
            case '3': //Third case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText4';
                var option2 = document.createElement('option');
                    option2.text = 'SomeText5';
                var option3 = document.createElement('option');
                    option3.text = 'SomeText6';
                count = 3;
                break;
        }
        //populate select menu
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //how can I do this part?
            item.appendChild((option + i + 1));
        }
    }

//HTML

<p>Select Something:</p>

<div style="width:50%;">
        First Menu: <br>
        <select id='_first' required>
            <option value='0'>Select Type:</option>
            <option value='1'>First Option</option>
            <option value='2'>Second Option</option>
            <option value='3'>Third Option</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div style="width:50%;">
        Dynamic Second Menu: <br>
        <select id='_second'>
            <!-- Doesn't populate! &sadface; -->
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't append the value of a variable to another variable to get the name, and subsequently the value of another variable. Try using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) instead.

Comment: eval(), my answer is below. It shows how to do it, just use the eval() and parseInt() logic to add it into your own code Lego. good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 1; 
var option1 = 'test';
var option2 = 'test2';
var number = eval("option"+parseInt(i+1, 10)); 
console.log(number);
```

Here is it working... https://jsfiddle.net/ucp9jgnh/1/
Should do the trick... Not a great way to do it, but it will at least work

In this example, option2 is the answer...

parseInt(i+1, 10) ...that part will make sure it's i (your loop) +1 in a math format. Then it adds that to "option" text, and eval() then allows JS to look at it as a variable instead of a string.

If you change var i = 0, it will instead output 'test' instead of 'test2' because of the math.

Here is what you would do inside your loop... Should work as is:

```
var appendedThing = eval("option"+parseInt(i+1, 10));
item.appendChild(appendedThing);
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to build up an array of options like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpbKBx

```
//Javascript
    function myFunction () {

        //get value of selected <option> in a separate <select> drop down
        var type = document.getElementById('_first').value;
        //get the second <select>
        var item = document.getElementById('_second');

        //Clear child nodes from dynamic <select>
        while (item.hasChildNodes()) {
            item.removeChild(item.lastChild);
        }

        //set count variable to know how many <options> there should be in second <select> drop down
        var count;
        var options = [];
        //assess value
        switch (type) {
            case '1': //First case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText1';
                options.push(option1);
                break;
            case '2': //Second case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText2';
                options.push(option1);
                var option2 = document.createElement('option');
                    option2.text = 'SomeText3';
                options.push(option2);
                break;
            case '3': //Third case
                var option1 = document.createElement('option');
                    option1.text = 'SomeText4';
                options.push(option1);
                var option2 = document.createElement('option');
                    option2.text = 'SomeText5';
                options.push(option2);
                var option3 = document.createElement('option');
                    option3.text = 'SomeText6';
                options.push(option3);
                break;
        }

        //populate select menu
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            //how can I do this part?
            item.appendChild((options[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just got awarded answer, but I just wanted to say that this answer from Bensmind is also legitimate, and a recommended option. It does change the structure of the OP's code, but is an efficient way of doing it. If there were hundreds of options, Ben's code would be faster than mine I believe - if not faster (to run, not to code) already.

Comment: I meant nothing personal, it's just that your answer fit my situation a bit more. I am not able to approach this problem with using an array as a solution, but it would definitely work.. just not for my situation. All great answers, thank you